# How can I get the value of first element which is inside another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```js
var s = '<a class="chosen-single chosen-default">\
            <span>value1</span>\
            <div><b>wsefw</b></div>\
            <span>value2</span>\
            link\
         </a>';

console.log(s.find(".chosen-single > span:first-child").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

All I want to get is `value1`. So I want to get the value of the first `<span>` which is into `a.chosen-single`. How can I do that?

Comment: `var value = anotherElement.firstChild.value;`

Comment: @Teemu what's `anotherElement` ?

Comment: The one from your title. Maybe it needs some elaboration ..?

Answer (score 1):

Turn it into DOM, then:

```js
var s = $('<a class="chosen-single chosen-default">\
            <span>value1</span>\
            <div><b>wsefw</b></div>\
            <span>value2</span>\
            link\
         </a>');

console.log(s.find('span').eq(0).text()); // or just span:first-child
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for selector like this:

```
$(".chosen-single > span:first").text()
```